# g++ not linking header files properly

Tags: gcc, cygwin, g++, linker

I am using cygwin libraries to run C and C++ programs on Windows.

`gcc` runs fine, but with `g++`, I get a long list of errors. I think these erros are because of linking problems with C libraries.

***Can you suggest what I need to do to fix this?***

---

**beginning error lines:**

```
In file included from testgpp.cpp:1:
/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/cstdio:52:19: stdio.h: No such file or directory
In file included from testgpp.cpp:1:
/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/cstdio:99: error: `::FILE' has not been declared
/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/cstdio:100: error: `::fpos_t' has not been declared
/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/cstdio:102: error: `::clearerr' has not been declared
/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/cstdio:103: error: `::fclose' has not been declared
/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/cstdio:104: error: `::feof' has not been declared
```

**the whole error dump:**
[PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/dfDj6YBi)

---

for people asking for source code: this this is clearly a header file linking issue and happens before the compilation even starts. I get the same error for every .cpp file.

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout<<"hello world!";    
}
```

gives me the very same error.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos: `g++ testgpp.cpp`

Comment: Without seeing more details, I can't give you an answer, but if you are including "windows.h"... it is known to interact very poorly with Cygwin and may sometimes cause errors similar to the above.

Comment: Can you post the contents of testgpp.cpp?

Comment: And also g++ --version would help, as well.

Comment: @Michael Aaron Safyan: What details do you want to know?

Comment: `g++ (GCC) 3.4.4 (cygming special, gdc 0.12, using dmd 0.125)`

Comment: What about gcc? Are you using g++3 with gcc4?

Comment: no, `gcc (GCC) 3.4.4 (cygming special, gdc 0.12, using dmd 0.125)`

Comment: Hm... sorry, I don't know what could be causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key error is:

```
In file included from testgpp.cpp:1:
[...]/include/c++/cstdio:52:19: stdio.h: No such file or directory
```

The fact that G++ is complaining that it cannot find `<stdio.h>` (though it leaves the angle brackets out of the message) means you have a compiler configuration problem of some sort.  Probably, you are missing a crucial package.  I would look to reinstall or update your GCC environment, so that `<stdio.h>` ends up being found.

The rest of the problems are consequences of the missing header - the compiler is struggling on without all the information it needs to avoid generating unwarranted errors.